# error in using optionmenu widget in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

I have written a code in python 2.7 which implements "optionmenu" widget. I am facing a problem that i have given six values in the tuple but when i select another option rather than "Gmail", i see only five values in the dropdown. can anyone tell me my mistake?

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

choices = ("Gmail", "Outlook/Hotmail", "Yahoo", "Comcast", "AT&T", "Verizon")
dropdown_var = StringVar()
dropdown_var.set(choices[0]) # set default value

def data(*args):
    value = dropdown_var.get()
    print(value)

l = ttk.Label(root, text="Select your e-mail provider : ")
l.pack(side="left")

option = ttk.OptionMenu(root, dropdown_var, *choices)
option.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

b = ttk.Button(root, text="Click", command=data)
b.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is linked to the way you are defining the `OptionMenu` widget.

In fact, it's different from the tkinter OptionMenu because you set the default value inside the declaration. So when you unpack the values, the first index `"Gmail"` is taken as the `default` parameter for the widget, and the others are the options values.

(In addition, you don't need to set `dropdown_var` before)

Try this version :

```
choices = ("Gmail", "Outlook/Hotmail", "Yahoo", "Comcast", "AT&T", "Verizon")
dropdown_var = StringVar()

def data(*args):
    value = dropdown_var.get()
    print value # no bracket for python2

l = ttk.Label(root, text="Select your e-mail provider : ")
l.pack(side="left")

# the 3rd parameter is the default value    
option = ttk.OptionMenu(root, dropdown_var, choices[0], *choices) 
option.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)
```